# How to get list of Azure Subscriptions and other details during login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to make the user login in my custom application and Get the list of Tenants and Once I Get i want to make other Graph API calls like getting list of Azure Resource Groups etc

I want to build a similar experience just like we see in Microsoft Documentation (Try It) section. So that to get details from Users Azure Account i wont have to create Azure AD application in their Subscription

For e.g. [image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a multi-tenant app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Multi-tenant app should be the option as juunas suggested.